# Disable keyboard on mobile device for react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

So im using the [react-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker) npm plugin and I'm trying to disable my mobile phone keyboard from showing when I click on it because my phones keyboard takes up the whole screen so it's hard to interact the datepicker on mobile

this is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import Label from './Label';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css';


const Example = (props) => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
  
  return (
    <div className="customDatePickerWidth">
      <Label className={props.className} text={props.label}></Label>
      <DatePicker 
       
        className={""+props.class} selected={startDate} 
        onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} 
        disabledKeyboardNavigation
        placeholderText="dd/mm/yyyy"

        />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Example;
```

Comment: `disabledKeyboardNavigation` just means that you can't arrow around on the calendar view to select a day, it doesn't mean "disable the keyboard altogether".  I don't see an option native to the control to do that.  You'd probably have to hook into the control's textbox events.

Answer (score 10):

I had this same problem today and discovered an open issue in react-datepicker where there seem to be a few work arounds. [This one](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1480#issuecomment-574046673) ended up working for me:

```
  <DatePicker 
    className={""+props.class} selected={startDate} 
    onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} 
    disabledKeyboardNavigation
    placeholderText="dd/mm/yyyy"
    onFocus={e => e.target.blur()} // <--- Adding this
  />
```

Comment: Wanted to point out that 4 years later, this still works.